# I want change the column datatype so I can install doctrine/dbal but i am not able to

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am installing `composer require doctrine/dbal` but due to the php version I am not being able to do so.

- php version is 8.2.0
- laravel version is 10

[image: error screnshot]

Comment: hey. do `composer update --with-all-dependencies`.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, you are using laravel 9, not laravel 10

Comment: The error is self explanatory, you have PHP 8.2 but it requires 7.1+ (not including 8.x+), the issue is that you have Laravel 9 as the last item on the problem 1 mentions you have Laravel framework (`laravel/framework`) 9.31...

Comment: Why are you not able to do that? Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: reading the error messages really helps. Sometimes developers create useful output. This is one of those cases

Answer (score -1):

you can use [3.7.x](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.7.x/composer.json) version temporarily and send pull request for [4.0.x](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/4.0.x/composer.json) version or [write issue](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues)

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1|^8.2"
}
```

or [Version Range](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#version-range)

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=^8.1"
}
```

Comment: Both v3.7 and v4 of `doctrine/dbal`  are compatible with PHP 8.2. Please add some explanation to your answer such that others understand how it resolves the initial problem